# What happens if a mantra / sadhana is siddha?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, siddhi, sadhana

Basically we everytime come to know that in order to make a mantra / sadhana work for you, it should be siddha first. There are different types of sadhana / siddhi for different purposes. I wanted to know what happens during a mantra siddhi process. For Ex : If one is doing a sadhana for say 40 days to attain siddhi over some deity for a boon or power. So what obstacles one has to face during and after completion of it.

Update : Also, in Bhagavad Gita as **Krishna** says that those who worship demigods go to their kingdom, so is it like attaining siddhis is kind of less achievement than attaining moksha/nirvana/enlightenment ?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. It seems like you are asking for personal experiences of users while attaining Siddhis. Asking for personal exper is off-topic for our site since we can't verify their correctness. Please remove that portion which asks for personal experiences or opinions. See [help/on-topic] and [ask] pages.

Comment: I have modified that part and updated my question.